# get label (Name) instead QID field

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Using the following query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?director WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  ?item wdt:P161 wd:Q2263 .
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P57 ?director .} 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

I can get movies with Tom Hanks and QID of director.

But how can I get director's name (label of this QID) in this table.

Query can be seen on [Wikidata Query Service page](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%3Fdirector%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP161%20wd%3AQ2263%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP57%20%3Fdirector%20.%7D%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `?directorLabel` to the select. The label service seems to work on any declared variable if you suffix it with 'Label'